# Cassandra CQL versions

Tags: cassandra, cql

What version of CQL is CQLv4?  Looking at the product compatibility page of the documentation shows versions 3.4, 3.3, 3.2... etc.  Does the v4 in CQLv4 stand for 3.4?

I'm trying to find which versions of Cassandra are compatible with CQLv4.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/compatibility.html?scroll=compatibilityDocument__cql-versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [this table](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/native_protocol/) could do a better job for you. Protocol version 4 starts with Cassandra 2.2, and continues to version 3.x